# JS Async/Await isn't working in combination with forEach

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Here is the code I'm working with (IP address censored for obvious reasons):

```
async function buildJobsView() {
    let jobList = await getJobs()
    Promise.all([getJobs()]).then($("#jobsPane").text(jobList))
}

async function getJobs() {
    //Open API connection and submit
    var url = "http://IPADDRESS:8082/api/jobs?IdOnly=true"
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("GET", url, true)
    xhr.send()
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
            return xhr.response
        }
    }
}
```

For whatever reason, the `jobList` variable is being assigned before the `getJobs()` function finishes running.  The `getJobs()` function does return the right output eventually, but the code has already moved on. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You dont need async on second function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` doesn't automatically convert callback-based code into Promise-based code - you have to explicitly convert the callback to a Promise and return a Promise whenever you want to be able to use it as a Promise.

```
function getJobs() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    //Open API connection and submit
    var url = "http://IPADDRESS:8082/api/jobs?IdOnly=true"
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("GET", url, true)
    xhr.send()
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
        resolve(xhr.response)
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Then, `getJobs` will return a Promise, and then you can consume it with `await`:

```
const jobList = await getJobs()
```

Comment: OH THANK GOD!!!! that was what I was missing.  I'm also still getting used to the whole => coding structure.  Not even sure exactly what it means.  I haven't been deep into web development in about 8 years, so I'm way behind on standards and updates.  It all feels so unintuitive to me.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to, but I got so excited I forgot to come back.  The reply was so fast after I posted that I wasn't allowed to accept it.